# Equivalent of C++ std::setprecision(n) using printf in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to set custom precision using printf()

like for example:

```
double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
cin>>n;
cout<<setprecision(n)<<pi;
```

I want to implement this same functionality using printf()

Comment: [printf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: You specify it in the optional parameters of `%f`.

Comment: Specifically, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160#precision).

Comment: And if you want to get it dynamically from a variable, you can use `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> (optional) `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies precision of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the argument to be converted, but after the argument supplying minimum field width if one is supplied.

So:

```
int n = ...;

printf("%.*f\n", n, pi);
```